# Why are execute permissions along with write permissions needed for creating a file in C (Linux)?

Tags: linux, permissions, c

I am trying to create a file from my C source code on linux. I am using the `dd` command for reading from a file and writing it to a file by creating it. If I don't have execute permissions (I have write permissions) for the target directory (where the file is going to be created), it is unable to create the file. If I have both write and execute permissions, it is able to create file.

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When set, the r, w, and x mode attributes have the following effect on files and
directories:

- r Attribute (read permission):

**Files:** Allows a file to be **opened** and **read**.

**Directories:** Allows a directory's contents to be listed. To retrieve any info about the containing files or directories, **the execute attribute must also be set.**

- w Attribute (write permission):

**Files:** Allows a file to be written to or truncated, however this attribute **does not allow files to be renamed or deleted**. The ability to delete or rename files is determined **by directory attributes**.

**Directories:** Allows files within a directory to be created, deleted, and renamed **if the execute attribute is also set**.

- x Attribute (execute permission):

**Files:** Allows a file to be treated as a program and executed. Program files written in scripting languages **must also be set as readable to be executed**.

**Directories:** Allows a directory to be **entered**, e.g., cd directory.

Reference: The Linux® Command Line William E. Shotts, Jr.

I would recommend to read this book or pdf version which you can download it from this link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxcommand/files/TLCL/13.07/TLCL-13.07.pdf/download

Answer (score 0):

The execution bit on a directory grants you the possibility to enter/trasverse it. Therefore it's a prerequisite to create a file (otherwise you can enter it) aswell in your case.